# No javascript project enlisted in visual studio 2012 ultimate

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I have installed visual studio ultimate 2012 for windows 8 store apps but it doesnt show JavaScript in the new project.

The setup is good, i have installed it before using the same setup but i dont know what is the problem now..

I have also tried Visual studio Express, but got the same issue.. And one more thing BLEND is also not working in both the cases.

Comment: Which express did you try? I just verified it, they show up so lets go over some basics. What version OS are you installing this on. Which version of express did you download? I did: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-8

Comment: Also did you install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling the current VS and then deleting all registries and finally installing Vs 2012 ultimate, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking in the right place? They can be 'hidden' in "Other Languages"
Search in the upper right hand corner of "New Project" for javascript to be sure.

Make sure you are up to date as well on the following updates as good measure

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188

Comment: I have checked many times. There is no sign of javascript new project.